# Making sure 0 gets white in a RdBu colorbar

Tags: matplotlib, colorbar, colormap

I create a heatmap with the following snippet:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
d = np.random.normal(.4,2,(10,10))
plt.imshow(d,cmap=plt.cm.RdBu)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

The result is plot below:
[image]

Now, since the middle point of the data is not 0, the cells in which the colormap has value 0 are not white, but rather a little reddish.

**How do I force the colormap so that max=blue, min=red and 0=white?**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use a [`TwoSlopeNorm`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/colors/colormapnorms.html).

**Note:** Prior to matplotlib 3.2, `TwoSlopeNorm` was known as [`DivergingNorm`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.TwoSlopeNorm.html).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors

d = np.random.normal(.4,2,(10,10))

norm = mcolors.TwoSlopeNorm(vmin=d.min(), vcenter=0, vmax = d.max())
plt.imshow(d, cmap=plt.cm.RdBu, norm=norm)

plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: The class `DivergingNorm` has been renamed to `TwoSlopeNorm`, cf. [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/prev_api_changes/api_changes_3.2.0.html).

Answer (score 2):

A previous SO post ([Change colorbar gradient in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44432693/4050510)) wanted a solution for a more complicated situation, but one of the answers talked about the MidpointNormalize subclass in the [matplotlib documentation](https://matplotlib.org/users/colormapnorms.html). With that, the solution becomes:

```py
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class MidpointNormalize(mpl.colors.Normalize):
    ## class from the mpl docs:
    # https://matplotlib.org/users/colormapnorms.html

    def __init__(self, vmin=None, vmax=None, midpoint=None, clip=False):
        self.midpoint = midpoint
        super().__init__(vmin, vmax, clip)

    def __call__(self, value, clip=None):
        # I'm ignoring masked values and all kinds of edge cases to make a
        # simple example...
        x, y = [self.vmin, self.midpoint, self.vmax], [0, 0.5, 1]
        return np.ma.masked_array(np.interp(value, x, y))

d = np.random.normal(.4,2,(10,10))
plt.imshow(d,cmap=plt.cm.RdBu,norm=MidpointNormalize(midpoint=0))
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

Kudos to Joe Kington for writing the subclass, and to Rutger Kassies for pointing out the answer.

[image: Properly normalized midpoint in the heatmap]

Comment: In addition, you could also manually set the limits of the coloraxis