# Setting the Colorbar Midpoint Value

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, patch, colorbar

Take this piece of code which generates a random integer within a range, assigns it an RGBA colour, and then plots it as a patch.

```
import numpy
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
import matplotlib.colorbar as cbar
from matplotlib import cm
import random

class MidpointNormalize(mpl.colors.Normalize):
    def __init__(self,vmin=None,vmax=None,midpoint=None,clip=False):
        self.midpoint=midpoint
        mpl.colors.Normalize.__init__(self,vmin,vmax,clip)
    def __call__(self,value,clip=None):
        x,y=[self.vmin,self.midpoint,self.vmax],[0,0.5,1]
        return numpy.ma.masked_array(numpy.interp(value,x,y),numpy.isnan(value))

colors=plt.cm.RdBu(numpy.linspace(0,1,256))
colormap=mcolors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('colormap',colors)
normalisecolors=MidpointNormalize(vmin=-50,midpoint=0,vmax=100)
scalecolors=cm.ScalarMappable(norm=normalisecolors,cmap=colormap) 

fig,ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(8,8))
ax.set_xlim(0,100)
ax.set_ylim(0,100)

for x in range(0,100):
    for y in range(0,100):
        val=random.randint(-50,100)
        rgbacolor=scalecolors.to_rgba(val)
        ax.add_patch(patches.Polygon([(x,y),(x,y+1),(x+1,y+1),(x+1,y)],fill=True,facecolor=rgbacolor))

cax,_=cbar.make_axes(ax,orientation='horizontal',aspect=50,pad=0.12)
cb=cbar.ColorbarBase(cax,cmap=colormap,norm=normalisecolors,orientation='horizontal')
```

I want to modify the colour bar so that the colour white is represented by the value 0 (which is what I thought I'd done on line 20), but this hasn't worked:

[image]

I'd be grateful if anyone could suggest where I've gone wrong.

*I'd kindly ask contributors to refrain from suggesting alternative ways of plotting this data; the actual data I am plotting requires hundreds of lines of code to read and process output files from a numerical model. I've stripped away all of this code and replaced it with a random number generator to enable users to run the code themselves to help me.*

Comment: [How to set 0 to white at a uneven color ramp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59638155/7758804), [Making sure 0 gets white in a RdBu colorbar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57180317/7758804)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved this by using [TwoSlopeNorm](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.TwoSlopeNorm.html) instead:

```
normalisecolors=TwoSlopeNorm(vmin=-50,vcenter=0,vmax=100)
```

and by adding a key line of code:

```
cb.ax.set_xscale('linear')
```

The MidpointNormalize elements of the code are therefore redundant and have been removed.

The new code generates a plot and colour bar identical to previous versions of matplotlib.

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
from matplotlib.colors import TwoSlopeNorm
import matplotlib.colorbar as cbar
from matplotlib import cm
import random

colors=plt.cm.RdBu(numpy.linspace(0,1,256))
colormap=mcolors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('colormap',colors)
normalisecolors=TwoSlopeNorm(vmin=-50,vcenter=0,vmax=100)
scalecolors=cm.ScalarMappable(norm=normalisecolors,cmap=colormap) 

fig,ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(8,8))
ax.set_xlim(0,100)
ax.set_ylim(0,100)

for x in range(0,100):
    for y in range(0,100):
        val=random.randint(-50,100)
        rgbacolor=scalecolors.to_rgba(val)      # Calculate RGBA color code for value
        ax.add_patch(patches.Polygon([(x,y),(x,y+1),(x+1,y+1),(x+1,y)],fill=True,facecolor=rgbacolor))

cax,_=cbar.make_axes(ax,orientation='horizontal',aspect=50,pad=0.12)
cb=cbar.ColorbarBase(cax,cmap=colormap,norm=normalisecolors,orientation='horizontal')
cb.ax.set_xscale('linear')
```

[image]

Comment: If you have a concern about efficiency, use a PatchCollection

Answer (score 0):

The version of the [`MidpointNormalize` class](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormapnorms.html#custom-normalization-manually-implement-two-linear-ranges) in the latest version of the documentation (matplotlib v3.7.2, Aug 2023) has an extra method defined (`inverse`) which was not in previous versions (it appears to have changed between [v3.4.3](https://matplotlib.org/3.4.3/tutorials/colors/colormapnorms.html#custom-normalization-manually-implement-two-linear-ranges) and [v3.5.3](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.3/tutorials/colors/colormapnorms.html#custom-normalization-manually-implement-two-linear-ranges)).

The comment in that documentation suggests the `inverse` function is needed to get the colorbar to work. Also note that the interpolation in the `__call__` method extrapolates beyond vmin/vmax to +/- infinity, which was not there previously.

Modifying your code to include this gets the colorbar to work as requested:

```py
class MidpointNormalize(colors.Normalize):
    def __init__(self, vmin=None, vmax=None, vcenter=None, clip=False):
        self.vcenter = vcenter
        super().__init__(vmin, vmax, clip)

    def __call__(self, value, clip=None):
        # I'm ignoring masked values and all kinds of edge cases to make a
        # simple example...
        # Note also that we must extrapolate beyond vmin/vmax
        x, y = [self.vmin, self.vcenter, self.vmax], [0, 0.5, 1.]
        return np.ma.masked_array(np.interp(value, x, y,
                                            left=-np.inf, right=np.inf))

    def inverse(self, value):
        y, x = [self.vmin, self.vcenter, self.vmax], [0, 0.5, 1]
        return np.interp(value, x, y, left=-np.inf, right=np.inf)
```

Note also that the attribute `midpoint` has changed to `vcenter` here, so you also need to change your code which creates `normalisecolors` accordingly:

```py
normalisecolors=MidpointNormalize(vmin=-50,vcenter=0,vmax=100)
```

[image]